# How to reuse a cookie so, that the website knows I've already accept the terms?

Tags: javascript, puppeteer

Most websites when you load ask you to accept cookies and privacy, I think it's mainly in the EU.
I'm struggling on how to reuse the cookies so, I don't have to keep clicking "accept all", every time I load up chrome.

The way I'm thinking is that if I click on "accept all" the first time and save the cookie, I can write a code that fetches the cookie file and it knows I accepted the website cookie and so, it doesn't pop up again.

The website I'm using for this example is https://finviz.com/

```js
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer')
const fs = require('fs')
;(async () => {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ headless: false })
  const page = await browser.newPage()
  await page.goto('https://finviz.com/')

  const cookiesString = await fs.readFile('./cookies.json')
  const cookies = JSON.parse(cookiesString)
  await page.setCookie(...cookies)
})()
```

[image: Picture of privacy terms]

Comment: Do you want to use a cookie for your own website or do you want to "hack" the cookie of a foreign website that you visit?

Comment: the latter tbh, I just want it so, privacy terms don't keep popping up so, i could scrap the data

Comment: But if you click 'accept', the website saves automatically a cookie. So why do you need to write your own for tricking the website. Are you deleting the cookies everyday?

Comment: every time I exit chrome, I believe cookies are deleted
so, when I start it up back again, i need to accept it again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is at least complicated to write an app that listens for the setting of cookies to copy them to a file and put them back when the browser is restartet. The same applies for the case that you want to save the cookies manually.

But if you do that then deleting the cookies would be unnecessary - so you could simply allow cookies in the settings of your browser.

Comment: Yeahh agreed, thats definitely a simpler way of doing it
Apperciate the help
-C